# How to interpolate data from a table to find an equation?

Tags: python, database, numpy, interpolation

I need to interpolate a set of data of energy (`ε`) and pressure (`p`) in order to find an equation of the form `ε(p)`, i.e., energy in terms of pressure. I have tried something simple using `interp1d` but it seems to be wrong.

Observation: `εp` represents the equation that arises from the interporation of `ε` with `p`. But I believe that I'm doing something wrong, because it's giving this error and it doesn't seem to be generating an equation properly

The entire code and the error printed in the screen is below. Thank you for any help.

**CODE**

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

data_apr = np.loadtxt(r"C:\Users\Ramos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\\apr.dat")

m_apr = [] 
p_apr = [] #pressure
ε_apr = [] #energy

for i in range(1001):
    m_apr.append(data_apr[i][0])
    p_apr.append(data_apr[i][1])
    ε_apr.append(data_apr[i][2])

εp= interp1d(p_apr, ε_apr)

def f(u, kappa, εp, r):
    λ, v, p = u
    f = np.array([(1-math.exp(u[0])+math.exp(u[0])*(r**2)*kappa*εp)/r, (-1+math.exp(u[0])+math.exp(u[0])*(r**2)*kappa*u[2])/r, -(1/2)*(u[3]+εp)*((-1+math.exp(u[0])+math.exp(u[0])*(r**2)*kappa*u[2])/r)])
    return f

# Runge-Kutta Method

def RK2(u, f, dr, *args):
    u_i = u + dr * f(u, *args) / 2
    u_novo = u + dr * f(u_i, * args)
    return u_novo

#Constants
kappa = 1

dr=0.01
ri = 0.00001
rf = 2
N = int(rf/dr)

u = np.empty((N+1, 3))

#Initial Conditions
λ0 = 1
v0 = 1
p0 = p_apr[0]
u[0] = np.array([λ0, v0, p0])

r = np.arange(0.0001, 1.5, 0.01)

for i in range(N-1):
    u[i+1] = RK2(u[i], f, dr, kappa, εp, r[i])
    if u[i+1][2] < 0 or math.isnan(u[i+1][2]):
        raio = r[i]
        index = i
        break

print("r[index]:", raio)
print("index", index)
```

**ERROR**

```
f = np.array([(1-math.exp(u[0])+math.exp(u[0])*(r**2)*kappa*εp)/r, (-1+math.exp(u[0])+math.exp(u[0])*(r**2)*kappa*u[2])/r, -(1/2)*(u[3]+εp)*((-1+math.exp(u[0])+math.exp(u[0])*(r**2)*kappa*u[2])/r)])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'interp1d'
```

Comment: looks like kappa times εp needs to be kappa times εp(some input value)

Comment: εp represents the equation that arises from the interporation of ε with p. But I believe that I'm doing something wrong, because it's giving this error and it doesn't seem to be generating an equation properly.

Comment: the error is because it generates a function, which expects you to pass it a value. I don't know if everything else is right, but that's what's causing the error you shared.